# Can't move string from the stack back into a register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, intel

I'm new to assembly so, for the past week, I've been rewriting a lot of c functions in x86 asm (intel syntax) as exercises to teach myself the language. While I was struggling manipulating the stack in some function, I tried isolating the buggy lines of code and here is what I'm left with:

```
extern int my_func(const char *s);

int main(void)
{
    return my_func("700");
}
```

That is my main in c which gets compiled and linked with the following assembly code:

```
section .text
   global my_func

my_func:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp

  sub rsp, 8                 ; allocating stack memory to save both pointers

  mov qword [rsp], rdi       ; saving s


  mov rdx, qword [rsp]       ; moving s back into a register

  xor rax, rax               ; set return value to 0

  add rsp, 8                 ; clear stack
  pop rbp

  ret
```

I'm very aware that this function doesn't do anything, but when I inspect the stack frame and the registers through gdb, I can't ever find my pointer; and `rdx` never gets the right data. As if it was never actually saved to stack. The thing that is driving me crazy tho, is that doing the same operations with an integer works perfectly.

If anyone is willing to explain what's going on, I'd appreciate it a lot :)!

PS: I use `nasm -g -felf64 my_file.s` to assmeble and `gcc -g main.c my_file.o` to compile/link it all together.

Comment: That makes no sense, your manual push RDI / pop RDX should just be copying the incoming RDI to RDX.  If your debugger isn't showing that happening, your debugger may be broken, or you're using it wrong.  In GDB, `p (char*)$rdi` or `p (char*)$rdx` should print the string and the pointer value, if you do it after you've single-stepped past the execution of `mov rdx, [rsp]`.

Comment: Please post a transcript of your debugging session.  Most probably you are not inspecting what you think you are inspecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.. it's a bit embarrassing, but it turns out I was trying to print `rsp` the wrong way (I was doing `x/s $rsp`) and I now understand why it didn't work. And also, I realized I didn't test for `rdx`'s value in the code I provided. I did for the original code and the value was indeed wrong. But when simplifying the code for this post, I removed the lines that were causing the bug and just assumed they didn't have that big of an impact. Well, they did.
May this serve as a lesson for me and for anyone else in my situation. Thank you for pointing out my mistakes guys. I'll definitely be more careful in the future!

Comment: Yup, making a [mcve] is a good debugging technique when something isn't doing what you expect, as preparation for a question or bug report in case you don't discover a bug during the process.